# Configuring ActiveMQ Artemis client connection in WildFly

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

Is the ActiveMQ connection configuration URI properties, for example [`clientID`](https://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri) only possible to set through the URI?

I've used a setup similar to [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-jms/how-to-connect-wildfly-to-a-remote-activemq-artemis-server/). However, here the connection endpoint is defined as remote-connector which leaves no room for URI query parameters:

```xml
<outbound-socket-binding name="remote-artemis">
    <remote-destination host="127.0.0.1" port="5445"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

Comment: @JustinBertram It's ActiveMQ Artemis

Comment: You can define the parameters you want at the connector level when you define your connection factory in the messaging subsystem

Comment: @ehsavoie I've tried to look for any way to do this in the pooled-connection-factory, but it doesn't seem to have any way to set parameters like clientID.

Comment: In the <remote-connector> element you can add several param elements <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>

Comment: @JustinBertram I've been using the CORE for a while and it seems to work ok in test. However what I need is some way to set parameters in production should I need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `client-id` attribute on the `connection-factory` you've defined to connect to the remote instance of ActiveMQ Artemis, e.g.:

```xml
...
<remote-connector name="my-remote-connector" socket-binding="remote-artemis" />
...
<connection-factory name="MyRemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:/MyRemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="my-remote-connector" client-id="myClientID" />
...
```

You can set any of these other attributes on the `connection-factory` as outlined in the XML schema:

- `ha`
- `factory-type`
- `discovery-group`
- `enable-amq1-prefix`
- `use-topology-for-load-balancing`
- `client-failure-check-period`
- `connection-ttl`
- `call-timeout`
- `call-failover-timeout`
- `consumer-window-size`
- `consumer-max-rate`
- `confirmation-window-size`
- `producer-window-size`
- `producer-max-rate`
- `protocol-manager-factory`
- `compress-large-messages`
- `cache-large-message-client`
- `min-large-message-size`
- `dups-ok-batch-size`
- `transaction-batch-size`
- `block-on-acknowledge`
- `block-on-non-durable-send`
- `block-on-durable-send`
- `auto-group`
- `pre-acknowledge`
- `retry-interval`
- `max-retry-interval`
- `reconnect-attempts`
- `failover-on-initial-connection`
- `connection-load-balancing-policy-class-name`
- `use-global-pools`
- `scheduled-thread-pool-max-size`
- `thread-pool-max-size`
- `group-id`
- `deserialization-white-list`
- `deserialization-black-list`
- `initial-message-packet-size`

You can set transport properties on the `remote-connector` itself, e.g.:

```xml
...
<remote-connector name="my-remote-connector" socket-binding="remote-artemis">
   <param name="" value="" /> 
</remote-connector>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a sensible client-id!. However it does not grant me the ability to use the myriad of other client URI configuration parameters :-(

Comment: All the parameters you are talking about can be set on the acceptor or the connector

Comment: You're now talking about setting them on the AMQ server side; and that is true

Comment: no in wildfly, the same parameters can be set

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment(s). Hope that helps!

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other folks who run into this same issue in the future. Thanks!